# Números en Orden ascendente y Números pares en C

Tags: c, array

Necesito realizar un código en **`C`** que lea 30 números enteros.

1. Imprimir números de menor a mayor en un vector.
2. Imprimir en otro vector solo los números pares ingresados por el usuario.

Esto es lo que llevo hecho:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int vector[50],tam=10,i,j,aux;

printf ("Ingrese 30 Numeros Enteros, Por Favor:\n\n");

for (i=0;i<tam;i++)
{
    cout<<"Num["<<(i+1)<<"]= ";
    scanf("%d",&vector[i]);
}


for(i=0;i<tam;i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<tam;j++)
    {
        if(vector[i]>vector[j])
        {
            aux=vector[i];
            vector[i]=vector[j];
            vector[j]=aux;
        }
    }
}
printf (" \nVector Ordenado de Menor a Mayor: \n\n");

for(i=0;i<tam;i++)
{
    cout<<vector[i]<<" | ";
}
}
```

Comment: en c, necesito quitar la libreria iostream y dejar solo la stdio.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con el código que tenías puesto ya tienes conseguida la parte de ordenar de menor a mayor. Yo solo he hecho la traducción a c en las librerías que usabas, y también he añadido la parte de obtener el vector con los números pares. Para ello solo hay que utilizar el operador módulo (%). Te pongo aquí el código final

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
int vector[50],tam=10,i,j,aux;
int vector_pares[50];

printf ("Ingrese 30 Numeros Enteros, Por Favor:\n\n");

for (i=0;i<tam;i++)
{
    printf("Num[%d]=",(i+1));
    scanf("%d",&vector[i]);
}

for(i=0;i<tam;i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<tam;j++)
    {
        if(vector[i]>vector[j])
        {
            aux=vector[i];
            vector[i]=vector[j];
            vector[j]=aux;
        }
    }
}
printf (" \nVector Ordenado de Menor a Mayor: \n\n");

for(i=0;i<tam;i++)
{
    printf("%d ",vector[i]);
}



j=0;
for(i=0;i<tam;i++)
{
    if ( vector[i] % 2 == 0 ){
        vector_pares[j]=vector[i];
        j++;
    }


}

printf (" \nVector Incluyendo solo los pares: \n\n");

for(i=0;i<j;i++){
    printf("%d ",vector_pares[i]);
}

}
```

Comment: Gracias, a sido de mucha ayuda!!!